# ¿Por qué no puedo agregar nuevos datos al archivo txt? C++

Tags: c++, fstream

estoy desarrollando un programa que registre empleados y que guarde sus datos en un archivo txt para cuando vuelva a abrir el programa. al principio todo iba bien, el programa guardó los datos de los empleados registrados en el archivo txt correctamente, puse un condicional que me imprimiera un mensaje en pantalla en caso que el archivo.txt fallara al abrir:

```
entrada.open("registro.txt",ios::app); //Esto abre el programa

if (entrada.fail()) //este if verifica si el archivo "registro.txt" fallo al abrir
{
    cout<< "ERROR AL ABRIR EL ARCHIVO"<<endl; //mensaje de error si entra al if
    Sleep(1500);
}
```

pero aquí viene el problema: cerré el programa, lo abrí por segunda vez y registré nuevos empleados, pero cuando quise guardar los datos en el txt me imprimia el mensaje que le dije al programa que imprimiera en caso de que hubiera algun error al abrir el archivo. eliminé el archivo y el programa lo creó de nuevo correctamente, volví a registrar empleados y los datos se guardaron correctamente en el nuevo archivo txt, cerré el programa, lo abrí y cuando quise volver a registrar otro empleado al guardar su informacion me imprimia el mensaje de error. es como si solo me dejara guardar datos en el archivo la primera vez abierto el programa.

aquí estoy definiendo la entrada y la salida:

```
ofstream entrada;
ifstream salida;
```

aquí esta la función para la entrada de datos al archivo txt:

```
void guardardatosarchi()
{   
    entrada.open("registro.txt",ios::out|ios::app);     
    if (entrada.fail())
    {
        cout<< "ERROR AL ABRIR EL ARCHIVO"<<endl;
        Sleep(1500);
    }
    else
    {
        for(int fila=0;fila<4;fila++)
        {
            for(int columna=0;columna<4;columna++)
            {
                if(piso4[fila][columna].cubiculo==1)
                {
                    entrada<<piso4[fila][columna].Documento<<" "
                    <<piso4[fila][columna].nombre<<" "
                    <<piso4[fila][columna].apellido<<" "
                    <<piso4[fila][columna].fila<<" "
                    <<piso4[fila][columna].columna<<" "
                    <<piso4[fila][columna].direccion<<" "
                    <<piso4[fila][columna].numDoc<<" "
                    <<piso4[fila][columna].eps<<" "
                    <<piso4[fila][columna].nacimiento.anio<<" "
                    <<piso4[fila][columna].cargo<<" "
                    <<piso4[fila][columna].llamados_at<<" "
                    <<piso4[fila][columna].sexo<<" "
                    <<piso4[fila][columna].telefono<<" "
                    <<piso4[fila][columna].ult_evaluacion_lab<<" "
                    <<piso4[fila][columna].cubiculo<<" "
                    <<piso4[fila][columna].piso<<" "<<endl;
                }               
            }
        }
        for(int fila=0;fila<4;fila++)
        {
            for(int columna=0;columna<4;columna++)
            {
                if(piso3[fila][columna].cubiculo==1)
                {
                    entrada<<piso3[fila][columna].Documento<<" "
                //  <<piso3[fila][columna].doc<<" "
                    <<piso3[fila][columna].nombre<<" "
                    <<piso3[fila][columna].apellido<<" "
                    <<piso3[fila][columna].fila<<" "
                    <<piso3[fila][columna].columna<<" "
                    <<piso3[fila][columna].direccion<<" "
                    <<piso3[fila][columna].numDoc<<" "
                    <<piso3[fila][columna].eps<<" "
                    <<piso3[fila][columna].nacimiento.anio<<" "
                    <<piso3[fila][columna].cargo<<" "
                    <<piso3[fila][columna].llamados_at<<" "
                    <<piso3[fila][columna].sexo<<" "
                    <<piso3[fila][columna].telefono<<" "
                    <<piso3[fila][columna].ult_evaluacion_lab<<" "
                    <<piso3[fila][columna].cubiculo<<" "
                    <<piso3[fila][columna].piso<<" "<<endl;
                }
            }
        } 
        for(int fila=0;fila<4;fila++)
        {
            for(int columna=0;columna<4;columna++)
            {
                if(piso2[fila][columna].cubiculo==1)
                {
                    entrada<<piso2[fila][columna].Documento<<" "
                //  <<piso2[fila][columna].doc<<" "
                    <<piso2[fila][columna].nombre<<" "
                    <<piso2[fila][columna].apellido<<" "
                    <<piso2[fila][columna].fila<<" "
                    <<piso2[fila][columna].columna<<" "
                    <<piso2[fila][columna].direccion<<" "
                    <<piso2[fila][columna].numDoc<<" "
                    <<piso2[fila][columna].eps<<" "
                    <<piso2[fila][columna].nacimiento.anio<<" "
                    <<piso2[fila][columna].cargo<<" "
                    <<piso2[fila][columna].llamados_at<<" "
                    <<piso2[fila][columna].sexo<<" "
                    <<piso2[fila][columna].telefono<<" "
                    <<piso2[fila][columna].ult_evaluacion_lab<<" "
                    <<piso2[fila][columna].cubiculo<<" "
                    <<piso2[fila][columna].piso<<" "<<endl;
                }
            }
        } 
        for(int fila=0;fila<4;fila++)
        {
            for(int columna=0;columna<4;columna++)
            {
                if(piso1[fila][columna].cubiculo==1)
                {
                    entrada<<piso1[fila][columna].Documento<<" "
                //  <<piso1[fila][columna].doc<<" "
                    <<piso1[fila][columna].nombre<<" "
                    <<piso1[fila][columna].apellido<<" "
                    <<piso1[fila][columna].fila<<" "
                    <<piso1[fila][columna].columna<<" "
                    <<piso1[fila][columna].direccion<<" "
                    <<piso1[fila][columna].numDoc<<" "
                    <<piso1[fila][columna].eps<<" "
                    <<piso1[fila][columna].nacimiento.anio<<" "
                    <<piso1[fila][columna].cargo<<" "
                    <<piso1[fila][columna].llamados_at<<" "
                    <<piso1[fila][columna].sexo<<" "
                    <<piso1[fila][columna].telefono<<" "
                    <<piso1[fila][columna].ult_evaluacion_lab<<" "
                    <<piso1[fila][columna].cubiculo<<" "
                    <<piso1[fila][columna].piso<<" "<<endl;
                }
            }
        } 
        entrada.close();
        cout<<endl<<"DATOS GUARDADOS"<<endl;
        Sleep(1500);
    }   
//  menuprincipal();   
}
```

esta es la función para la salida de datos del archivo txt hacia el programa:

```
void recuperardatos()
{
    salida.open("registro.txt",ios::in);    
    if (salida.fail())
    {
        cout<< "ERROR AL ABRIR EL ARCHIVO"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        
        while(salida>>doc1>>nom>>ape>>fil>>col>>dir>>docum>>epeese>>naa>>car>>lla>>sex>>tel>>ult>>cub>>pis)
        {
            if(pis==3)
            {
                piso3[fil][col].Documento=doc1;
                //piso3[fil][col].doc=docum1;
                strcpy(piso3[fil][col].nombre, nom);
                strcpy(piso3[fil][col].apellido, ape);
                piso3[fil][col].fila=fil;
                piso3[fil][col].columna=col;
                piso3[fil][col].direccion=dir;
                piso3[fil][col].numDoc=docum;
                piso3[fil][col].eps=epeese;
                piso3[fil][col].nacimiento.anio=naa;
                piso3[fil][col].cargo=car;
                piso3[fil][col].llamados_at=lla;
                piso3[fil][col].sexo=sex;
                piso3[fil][col].telefono=tel;
                piso3[fil][col].ult_evaluacion_lab=ult;
                piso3[fil][col].cubiculo=cub;
                piso3[fil][col].piso=pis;
            }   
            
            if(pis==2)
            {
                piso2[fil][col].Documento=doc1;
            //  piso2[fil][col].doc=docum1;
                strcpy(piso2[fil][col].nombre, nom);
                strcpy(piso2[fil][col].apellido, ape);
                piso2[fil][col].fila=fil;
                piso2[fil][col].columna=col;
                piso2[fil][col].direccion=dir;
                piso2[fil][col].numDoc=docum;
                piso2[fil][col].eps=epeese;
                piso2[fil][col].nacimiento.anio=naa;
                piso2[fil][col].cargo=car;
                piso2[fil][col].llamados_at=lla;
                piso2[fil][col].sexo=sex;
                piso2[fil][col].telefono=tel;
                piso2[fil][col].ult_evaluacion_lab=ult;
                piso2[fil][col].cubiculo=cub;
                piso2[fil][col].piso=pis;
            }
            if(pis==1)
            {
                piso1[fil][col].Documento=doc1;
            //  piso1[fil][col].doc=docum1;
                strcpy(piso1[fil][col].nombre, nom);
                strcpy(piso1[fil][col].apellido, ape);
                piso1[fil][col].fila=fil;
                piso1[fil][col].columna=col;
                piso1[fil][col].direccion=dir;
                piso1[fil][col].numDoc=docum;
                piso1[fil][col].eps=epeese;
                piso1[fil][col].nacimiento.anio=naa;
                piso1[fil][col].cargo=car;
                piso1[fil][col].llamados_at=lla;
                piso1[fil][col].sexo=sex;
                piso1[fil][col].telefono=tel;
                piso1[fil][col].ult_evaluacion_lab=ult;
                piso1[fil][col].cubiculo=cub;
                piso1[fil][col].piso=pis;   
            }
            if(pis==4)
            {
                piso4[fil][col].Documento=doc1;
            //  piso4[fil][col].doc=docum1;
                strcpy(piso4[fil][col].nombre, nom);
                strcpy(piso4[fil][col].apellido, ape);
                piso4[fil][col].fila=fil;
                piso4[fil][col].columna=col;
                piso4[fil][col].direccion=dir;
                piso4[fil][col].numDoc=docum;
                piso4[fil][col].eps=epeese;
                piso4[fil][col].nacimiento.anio=naa;
                piso4[fil][col].cargo=car;
                piso4[fil][col].llamados_at=lla;
                piso4[fil][col].sexo=sex;
                piso4[fil][col].telefono=tel;
                piso4[fil][col].ult_evaluacion_lab=ult;
                piso4[fil][col].cubiculo=cub;
                piso4[fil][col].piso=pis;
            }
        }
    }
    salida.close();
}
```

Comment: El código que muestras, en principio, no parece tener errores. Si no te funciona puede que sea por algo que no has puesto en la pregunta. Prueba a generar un ejemplo mínimo que reproduzca el problema